# What pain point does Intelligent Children Design Pattern solve?

Tags: design, design-patterns

In absence of this pattern, `downcasting` is needed in the derived classes. My question is does this pattern solve only the problem of `downcasting`? And why is `downcasting` bad compared to the alternative offered by Intelligent Childrean Design Pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Intelligent children is used when there are two base classes at the root of separate but related class hierarchies. For example `Widget` and `WidgetRenderer` are the base classes and `ListBoxWidget` needs to be used by the `draw()` method of the `ListBoxWidgetRenderer`. So the `draw()` method will want to downcast the `Widget` pointer.

Downcasting is generally frowned on, so every fresh reader will have to be convinced that it's okay in a given situation. With this pattern the right pointer is made available at the right type.